# Does 120hz and 60 hz make a difrence in gaming?

Tags: display, gaming, fps

With some reaserch on google, looks like poeple say human can't distinguish 60hz and 120hz, but some says human can distinguish it easlly. So when gpu is powerful enough(rtx4080), would you choose 2k 240hz or 4k 60hz? I mean 4k provide much better video, but will it feel better on 240hz? I has never tried a 240hz monitor.

Comment: You may not be able to distinguish fine detail at more than 60Hz (or even 30Hz according to some), but you can easily detect motion far faster. The human brain is not a single minded computer that has to process one frame at a time, you catch details independently and alongside processing how something is moving and those two happen at different rates. 120Hz is absolutely smoother than 60Hz and you can absolutely tell the difference. If you are used to high framerates 30Hz feels like a sideshow. Personally I prefer 1080p @ 144Hz but everyone is different.

Comment: The problem is that this depends on you, your eyesight, your sensitivities to motion and how your brain works as well as what kind of games you play and even the settings you use. There is not really any one true answer that is correct for everyone.

Comment: so it depends on how fast the object move?

Comment: Overwatch (which is a game I could play at 240 FPS) had a tendency to switch to "Windowed" mode, which on my system locked the frame-rate to 60 FPS. When that happened I noticed it instantly, when I moved the mouse to look around.

The reason is vertical edges (walls of building and such) typically only move 1 or 2 pixels when you have a high frame rate - so the transition looks smooth - at 60 FPS they move 10 pixels at a time and that jumps out as a problem.

Comment: To answer your question get the max resolution you can at 120 Hz if your graphics card has headroom and your monitor is at max res then push up your frame rate.

Comment: Linus Tech Tips did a few videos about 60hz and 120hz and even 144 and more. They show clear examples on why this works with indept tests, seems that everyone has a benefit of this, where for some it is more than for others. Look them up at YouTube.